# How can we share data between the different steps of a Job in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch

Digging into Spring Batch, I'd like to know as to How can we share data between the different steps of a Job?

Can we use JobRepository for this? If yes, how can we do that?

Is there any other way of doing/achieving the same?

Answer (score 55):

From a step, you can put data into the `StepExecutionContext`.
Then, with a listener, you can promote data from `StepExecutionContext` to `JobExecutionContext`.

This `JobExecutionContext` is available in all the following steps.

Becareful : data must be short.
These contexts are saved in the `JobRepository` by serialization and the length is limited (2500 chars if I remember well).

So these contexts are good to share strings or simple values, but not for sharing collections or huge amounts of data.

Sharing huge amounts of data is not the philosophy of Spring Batch.
Spring Batch is a set of distinct actions, not a huge Business processing unit.

Comment: How would you share potentially large data, like in a collection? My itemProcessor generates a list (records to delete) and I need to pass that list down the flow for a tasklet to process (do the actual delete of records). Thx

Comment: Could job scope somehow help at this case ?

Comment: @MichoRizo I would recommend using a cache like redis/ecache if the list is huge. I like to keep the objects in context relatively smaller in size

Answer (score 51):

the job repository is used indirectly for passing data between steps (Jean-Philippe is right that the best way to do that is to put data into the `StepExecutionContext` and then use the verbosely named [`ExecutionContextPromotionListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/listener/ExecutionContextPromotionListener.html) to promote the step execution context keys to the `JobExecutionContext`.

It's helpful to note that there is a listener for promoting `JobParameter` keys to a `StepExecutionContext` as well (the even more verbosely named `JobParameterExecutionContextCopyListener`); you will find that you use these a lot if your job steps aren't completely independent of one another.

Otherwise you're left passing data between steps using even more elaborate schemes, like JMS queues or (heaven forbid) hard-coded file locations.

As to the size of data that is passed in the context, I would also suggest that you keep it small (but I haven't any specifics on the

Comment: This is confirmed by the documentation + example here : http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps

Comment: Damn, five years later and this question still has traction. Way to go Spring Batch :)

Comment: Could job scope somehow help at this case ?

Answer (score 31):

I would say you have 3 options:

1. Use `StepContext` and promote it to `JobContext` and you have access to it from each step, you must as noted obey limit in size
2. Create `@JobScope` bean and add data to that bean, `@Autowire` it where needed and use it (drawback is that it is in-memory structure and if job fails data is lost, migh cause problems with restartability)
3. We had larger datasets needed to be processed across steps (read each line in csv and write to DB, read from DB, aggregate and send to API) so we decided to model data in new table in same DB as spring batch meta tables, keep `ids` in `JobContext` and access when needed and delete that temporary table when job finishes successfully.

Comment: Regarding your 2 option . Can I access a bean set from reader class from writer class in this way ?

Comment: How do you mean set from reader? We created bean outside i configuration and injected it where needed. You can try and see how to promote something from reader to job scope but it seams to me as odd solution to define something with job scope in reader.

Comment: Could job scope somehow help at this case ?

Comment: Would really appreciate if you could provide an example for how to use the @JobScoped bean. suggestion 2

Getting the following error when trying it.

Method threw 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.nordea.omega.reporting.job.ReportResponseJobScope$$SpringCGLIB$$0.toString()

Answer (score 12):

Here is what I did to save an object which is accessible through out the steps.

1. Created a listener for setting the object in job context

```java
@Component("myJobListener")
public class MyJobListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

        String myValue = someService.getValue();
        jobExecution.getExecutionContext().putString("MY_VALUE", myValue);
    }
}
```

1. Defined the listener in the job context

```xml
<listeners>
         <listener ref="myJobListener"/>
</listeners>
```

1. Consumed the value in step using BeforeStep annotation

```java
@BeforeStep
public void initializeValues(StepExecution stepExecution) {

String value = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().getString("MY_VALUE");

}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use a Java Bean Object

1. Execute one step
2. Store the result in the Java object
3. Next step will refer the same java object to get the result stored by step 1

In this way you can store a huge collection of data if you want

Comment: In the next step how am i gonna get the object from 1st step. Whole point of the question is that

Comment: @Elbek Autowire it.  Your class in step one has the POJO autowired and sets the data, and your class in step two also has the same object autowired (should be the same instance unless you're doing remote partitioning) and uses the getter.

Comment: how did you autowire  a newly created instance in step 1 in step2?Hiow do you attach the new instance into spring context?

Comment: @ Component for the POJO, @ Autowired + Setters in the first step, @ Autowired + Getters in the subsequent. Use also the JobScope annotation in the Tasklets.

Answer (score 8):

You can store data in the simple object. Like:

```java
AnyObject yourObject = new AnyObject();

public Job build(Step step1, Step step2) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobName")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(step1)
            .next(step2)
            .build();
}

public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1Name")
            .<Some, Any> chunk(someInteger1)
            .reader(itemReader1())
            .processor(itemProcessor1())
            .writer(itemWriter1(yourObject))
            .build();
}

public Step step2() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2Name")
            .<Some, Any> chunk(someInteger2)
            .reader(itemReader2())
            .processor(itemProcessor2(yourObject))
            .writer(itemWriter2())
            .build();
}
```

Just add data to object in the writer or any other method and get it in any stage of next step

Answer (score 6):

Another very simply approach, leaving here for future reference:

```java
class MyTasklet implements Tasklet {
    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        getExecutionContext().put("foo", "bar");
    }
}
```

and

```java
class MyOtherTasklet implements Tasklet {
    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        getExecutionContext().get("foo");
    }   
}
```

`getExecutionContext` here is:

```java
ExecutionContext getExecutionContext(ChunkContext chunkContext) {
    return chunkContext.getStepContext()
                       .getStepExecution()
                       .getJobExecution()
                       .getExecutionContext();
}
```

Put it in a super class, in an interface as a `default` method, or simply paste in your `Tasklet`s.

Comment: And what if you use a Partinioner and run multiple threads??
Then the very minimum is unique keys.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ExecutionContextPromotionListener`:

```
public class YourItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Object> {
    private StepExecution stepExecution;
    public void write(List<? extends Object> items) throws Exception {
        // Some Business Logic

        // put your data into stepexecution context
        ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
        stepContext.put("someKey", someObject);
    }
    @BeforeStep
    public void saveStepExecution(Final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }
}
```

Now you need to add promotionListener to your job

```
@Bean
public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilder
        .get("step1")<Company,Company>  chunk(10)
        .reader(reader()).processor(processor()).writer(writer())
        .listener(promotionListener()).build();
}

@Bean
public ExecutionContextPromotionListener promotionListener() {
    ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener = new ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
    listener.setKeys(new String[] {"someKey"});
    listener.setStrict(true);
    return listener;
}
```

Now, in step2 get your data from job ExecutionContext

```
public class RetrievingItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Object> {
    private Object someObject;
    public void write(List<? extends Object> items) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
    @BeforeStep
    public void retrieveInterstepData(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        ExecutionContext jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
        this.someObject = jobContext.get("someKey");
    }
}
```

If you are working with tasklets, then use the following to get or put ExecutionContext

```
List<YourObject> yourObjects = (List<YourObject>) chunkContent.getStepContext().getJobExecutionContext().get("someKey");
```

Comment: It's easy to copy and paste the code from official documentation. Why You don't provide Your own implementation? Everybody know that its written in doc.

Comment: That’s what I did. I provided easy to understand part of code. And, is the same available on documentation? I didn’t know that.

Answer (score 1):

I was given a task to invoke the batch job one by one.Each job depends on another. First job result needs to execute the consequent job program.
I was searching how to pass the data after job execution. I found that this ExecutionContextPromotionListener comes in handy.

1) I have added a bean for "ExecutionContextPromotionListener" like below

```
@Bean
public ExecutionContextPromotionListener promotionListener()
{
    ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener = new ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
    listener.setKeys( new String[] { "entityRef" } );
    return listener;
}
```

2)  Then I attached one of the listener to my Steps

```
Step step = builder.faultTolerant()
            .skipPolicy( policy )
            .listener( writer )
            .listener( promotionListener() )
            .listener( skiplistener )
            .stream( skiplistener )
            .build();
```

3) I have added stepExecution as a reference in my Writer step implementation and populated in the Beforestep

```
@BeforeStep
public void saveStepExecution( StepExecution stepExecution )
{
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
}
```

4) in the end of my writer step, i populated the values in the stepexecution as the keys like below

```
lStepContext.put( "entityRef", lMap );
```

5)  After the job execution, I retrieved the values from the
`lExecution.getExecutionContext()` and populated as job response.

6) from the job response object, I will get the values and populate the required values in the rest of the jobs.

The above code is for promoting the data from the steps to ExecutionContext using ExecutionContextPromotionListener.
It can done for in any steps.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Batch creates metadata tables for itself (like `batch_job_execution`, `batch_job_execution_context`, `batch_step_instance`, etc).

And I have tested (using postgres DB) that you can have at least 51,428 chars worth of data in one column (`batch_job_execution_context.serialized_content`). It could be more, it is just how much I tested.

When you are using Tasklets for your step (like `class MyTasklet implements Tasklet`) and override the `RepeatStatus` method in there, you have immediate access to `ChunkContext`.

```
class MyTasklet implements Tasklet {

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(@NonNull StepContribution contribution, 
                                @NonNull ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        List<MyObject> myObjects = getObjectsFromSomewhereAndUseThemInNextStep();
        chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution()
        .getJobExecution()
        .getExecutionContext()
        .put("mydatakey", myObjects);
    }
}
```

And now you have another step with a different Tasklet where you can access those objects

```
class MyOtherTasklet implements Tasklet {

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(@NonNull StepContribution contribution, 
                                @NonNull ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        List<MyObject> myObjects = (List<MyObject>) 
        chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution()
        .getJobExecution()
        .getExecutionContext()
        .get("mydatakey"); 
    }
}
```

Or if you dont have a Tasklet and have like a Reader/Writer/Processor, then

```
class MyReader implements ItemReader<MyObject> {

    @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['mydatakey']}")
    List<MyObject> myObjects;
    // And now myObjects are available in here

    @Override
    public MyObject read() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using `Tasklets`. No need to access the execution context. I used a map as the data element to move around. (Kotlin code.)

#### Tasklet

```
class MyTasklet : Tasklet {

    lateinit var myMap: MutableMap<String, String>

    override fun execute(contribution: StepContribution, chunkContext: ChunkContext): RepeatStatus? {
        myMap.put("key", "some value")
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED
    }

}
```

#### Batch configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var jobBuilderFactory: JobBuilderFactory

    @Autowired
    lateinit var stepBuilderFactory: StepBuilderFactory

    var myMap: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()

    @Bean
    fun jobSincAdUsuario(): Job {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("my-SO-job")
                .incrementer(RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(stepMyStep())    
                .next(stepMyOtherStep())        
                .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun stepMyStep() = stepBuilderFactory.get("MyTaskletStep")        
        .tasklet(myTaskletAsBean())
        .build()

    @Bean
    fun myTaskletAsBean(): MyTasklet {
        val tasklet = MyTasklet()
        tasklet.myMap = myMap      // collection gets visible in the tasklet
        return tasklet
    }
}
```

Then in `MyOtherStep` you can replicate the same idiom seen in `MyStep`. This other Tasklet will see the data created in `MyStep`.

**Important**:

- tasklets are created via a `@Bean fun` so that they can use `@Autowired` ([full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47712005/317522)).
- for a more robust implementation, the tasklet should implement `InitializingBean` with

```
    override fun afterPropertiesSet() {
        Assert.notNull(myMap, "myMap must be set before calling the tasklet")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nenad Bozic said in his 3rd option, use temp tables to share the data between steps, using context to share also does same thing, it writes to table and loads back in next step, but if you write into temp tables you can clean at the end of job.