# spring-batch : load and use a property file

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new on Spring batch so am here to ask some basic advice.

What is the best approach to load a config file in memory (or bean) and use its content while the spring Job/step are running ?

I am not sure but based on some google search I found the below scenario even if I dont  quite understand why I should define a writer even if i dont need it :

1. step1 : load config file (the content is two field delimited by =)
2. step2 : perform some java code and use the previous config file

so for the step 1 :

```
<bean id="inputFile" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource" scope="step">
    <constructor-arg value="path_config_file"/>
</bean>

<bean id="readerConfigFile" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" ref="inputFile"/>
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="field,value"/>
                    <property name="delimiter" value="="/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="configProperties"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="outputConfig" class="outputConfig"></bean>

<bean id="configProperties" class="configProperties" scope="prototype"/>
```

so my question are :

1. How can I use the information gathered in the file ? Should I put them in the Java bean ?
2. How can I pas this info between different step or make them persistent in the whole application life-cycle ?
3. Would you recommend to use a itemProcessor to achieve the above ?

Any advice are most than welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about your questions because I think you only need to load a properties file in spring context using a `PropertiesFactoryBean`:

```
    <bean id="config" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
      <property name="location">
        <value>file:path_config_file</value>
      </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="propertiesArray">
        <list>
          <ref bean="config"/>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

and you can refer to property values using ${} placeholder; but this solution is unrelated to spring-batch; I don't need it!

About your questions:

1. Using a POJO is a good way because spring-batch offers in-box mapping strategies (`BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper` in your case)
2. Objects used in a job are accessible only in job context, not in application context (this is why I think you need a `PropertiesFactoryBean`).
   To pass object between steps read [How can we share data between the different steps of a Job in Spring Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292667/how-can-we-share-data-between-the-different-steps-of-a-job-in-spring-batch)
3. `ItemProcessor` is requested if you need to convert an object `T` read from a `ItemReader<T>` to an object of type S written by an `ItemWriter<S>`. So no, you don't need an `ItemProcessor`.

I hope I was clear, English is not my native language

Comment: Yes, I just want to load a property file and use the file content in my application. Your answer resolved some doubts and put myself on the right direction. Didnt know about POJO .. Great.

Thanks Bellabax