# Spring batch to aggregate values and write single value

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch and I need to achieve the following

1. Read a csv file which has details like date and amount
2. Aggregate the sum of all amounts for a same date
3. Persist one entry with date and the sum

I have used batch in  the past and I thought of the following approach. Create a batch with 2 steps.

**Step 1:**

1. Reader:  Loop through the entire file using FlatFileItemReader
2. Processor: Populate a map with Key as date and value as amount. If entry is present then get the value and add it to the new value
3. Writer: No operation writer as I do not wish to write

**Step 2:**

1. Reader: Loop through the values of the map
2. Writer: Persist the values

I was able to acheive step 1 where I populated the `Map`. This `Map` has been declared with `@JobScope`

I am stuck at how do I create the reader for step2 which needs to just read the List of values. I tried `ListItemReader` but I am not able to access the `Map` from the `ListItemReader`.

Please advise a solution or if you have a better approach to tackle this

Thanks

Comment: please post the relevant parts of your code ... how exactly did you declared the Map and what does your Reader for Step 2 looks like ?

Comment: You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292667/how-can-we-share-data-between-the-different-steps-of-a-job-in-spring-batch (2 options StepContext or use Java Bean)

Answer (score 5):

Option 1:
If your cvs is already sorted by date, you could implement a group reader, which reads lines until a key value changes. After that, the whole group can be passed as one item to the processor.

Such a group reader could look like this:

```
  private SingleItemPeekableItemReader<I> reader;
  private ItemReader<I> peekReaderDelegate;

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    Assert.notNull(peekReaderDelegate, "The 'itemReader' may not be null");
    this.reader= new SingleItemPeekableItemReader<I>();
    this.reader.setDelegate(peekReaderDelegate);
  }

  @Override
  // GroupDTO is just a simple container. It is also possible to use
  // List<I> instead of GroupDTO<I>
  public GroupDTO<I> read() throws Exception {
    State state = State.NEW; // a simple enum with the states NEW, READING, and COMPLETE
    GroupDTO<I> group = null;
    I item = null;

    while (state != State.COMPLETE) {
      item = reader.read();

      switch (state) {
        case NEW: {
          if (item == null) {
            // end reached
            state = State.COMPLETE;
            break;
          }

          group = new GroupDTO<I>();
          group.addItem(item);
          state = State.READING;
          I nextItem = reader.peek();
          // isGroupBreak returns true, if 'item' and 'nextItem' do NOT belong to the same group
          if (nextItem == null || getGroupBreakStrategy.isGroupBreak(item, nextItem)) {
            state = State.COMPLETE;
          }
          break;
        }
        case READING: {
          group.addItem(item);

          // peek and check if there the peeked entry has a new date
          I nextItem = peekEntry();
          // isGroupBreak returns true, if 'item' and 'nextItem' do NOT belong to the same group
          if (nextItem == null || getGroupBreakStrategy.isGroupBreak(item, nextItem)) {
            state = State.COMPLETE;
          }
          break;
        }
        default: {
          throw new org.springframework.expression.ParseException(groupCounter, "ParsingError: Reader is in an invalid state");
        }
      }
    }

    return group;
  }
```

You need a SingleItemPeekableItemReader, in order to pre-read the next element. This one wraps your normal reader.

Option 2:
Step one is as you have proposed, but simply write a tasklet for step 2. There is no need to use reader-process-writer approach, instead a simple tasklet could be used that writes the content of your map to a file.

Option 3:
If you really wanna use a reader-processor-writer approach for step 2, write your own reader that iterates over your map.

something like (I did not test that code):

```
public class MapReader implements ItemReader {

     private MapContainer container;
     private Iterator<Map.Entry<Date, Integer> mapIterator;

     @PostConstruct
     public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        Assert.notNull(container);
        iterator = container.getMap().entry().iterator;
     }

     public void setMapContainer(MapContainer container) {
         this.container = container;
     }

     public Map.Entry<Date, Integer> read() {
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
           return iterator.next();
        }
        return null;
      }
}

@Component
public class MapContainer {
    private Map<Date, Integer> data = new Hashmap<>();

    public Map<Date, Integer> getMap() {
        return data;
    }

    // add modifier method as needed for step 1

}
```

so, you create a single spring-bean instance for the Container, inject it in your processor of step 2, fill it there, also inject it in the reader above.