# How to pass data between steps in Spring Batch

Tags: parameter-passing, spring-batch

How to pass data between steps in Spring Batch job using Java configuration and not XML configuration ?

Comment: so do you have configuration in xml & simply want a corresponding Java config? Elaborate more as what kind of data you wish to pass on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we share data between the different steps of a Job in Spring Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292667/how-can-we-share-data-between-the-different-steps-of-a-job-in-spring-batch).
This answer contains a javaconfig example, but convert XML to javaconfig is not so hard so you can easly try yourself. Enjoy.

Comment: Actually I don't have the XML config, I started all my project with Java config only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to share data between steps without any XML config :
First thing is to make the Tasklets classes implements `StepExecutionListener` and for the tasklet that's sending data put :

```
@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {}

@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().putString("test_key","test_value");
    return null;
}
```

and the second tasklet that must get data put :

```
@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    test = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().getString("test_key");
}

@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    return null;
}
```