# Can we use @Autowired in a Tasklet in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch tasklet as follows in my application.

```
@Service
public class SampleTasklet implements Tasklet {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution,
                                ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        System.err.println(userService.getUsers().size());
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

}
```

and I have a Service Class as follows.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class UserService {
    public Map<String, String> getUsers(){
        return null
    }

}
```

Spring Boot class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class SampleBatchApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Custom DAM Batch Application starting");
        SpringApplication.run(SampleBatchApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Spring Batch File: -- EDITED as per comments.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SampleBatch {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public SampleTasklet sampleTasklet;

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }
       
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .tasklet(sampleTasklet)
                .build();
    }

}
```

When I start my application I get an error as follows.

`Field userService in SampleTasklet required a bean of type 'UserService' that could not be found.`

Can you please explain this weird behavior? I have tried looking for this in multiple places and I think we can't @autowire a service class inside a tasklet. Am I correct?

Comment: Can you show your Spring Configuration? Looks like the UserService Bean is not present in the Spring Container.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic it is a spring boot application. I have edited the question with the spring boot class.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic Do you also need a Spring Batch configuration? Let me know the same.

Comment: Mhh, a look at the package structure would also help. Check that your UserService and SampleTasklet are picked up by Springs Component Scan.

Comment: Thanks for your response @mrkernelpanic. In spring boot application, does it matter ? Have attached the error logs as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK I found the error.

In your `SampleBatch` you declare your Bean `SampleTasklet` in Java Config. That means you have to make sure all dependencies get injected. That is why you do not get the `UserService` autowired.

Make sure that the UserService gets set in

```
@Bean
public SampleTasklet sampleTasklet(UserService userService){
    return new SampleTasklet(userService);
}
```

and do not forget to add this constructor in your `SampleTasklet` and assign the UserService there.

```
public class SampleTasklet implements Tasklet {

private UserService userService;

    public SampleTasklet (UserService userService){
        this.userService=userService;
    }
```

Comment: Will try the same. and let u know. I have tried doing Autowired of SampleTasklet instead of Bean. I got the error that i mentioned earlier

Comment: and remove `@Service` if you instantiate the Beans yourself. You have to decide what you want/ need. Either full handling of Spring or mixed or ...

Comment: Doing it via @Bean seems to be bit complex and messy. Is it possible to do via Autowired annotation so that i need not manage what needs to injected?

Comment: Thanks for your continued. Doing it via @Bean seems to be bit complex and messy. Is it possible to do via Autowired annotation so that i need not manage what needs to injected? Not sure whether spring batch supports for creating steps?

Comment: Sure, just autowire your `SampleTasklet` in your `SampleBatch` configuration. But then you have to add `@Service` again to the `SampleTasklet` and also autowire the UserService.

Comment: I have tried autowiring and i have updated the code in the question. I still get  userService in SampleTasklet required a bean of type 'UserService' that could not be found.

Comment: It looks to me that from Spring Batch we cannot autowire a tasklet that can inturn autowire a service class. Is it correct?  @mrkernelpanic

Comment: No that is wrong, double check your packages where your UserService resides vs your Spring Config/ Application.I assume your component-scan won't detect the UserService as a bean.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your UserService class located? Since one of the things`@SpringBootApplication` annotation does is a component scan, but it will only scan on sub-packages. i.e. if your `SampleBatchApp` class is in com.mypackage, then it will scan for all classes in sub-packages i.e. com.mypackage.*.

Or other alternative is to use a `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.mypackage"})`

Answer (score 0):

I added @Component and @Configuration to the class and an @Autowired to my service instance in the TaskLet class, as shown:

```java
@Component
@Configuration
public class CrawlerTask implements Tasklet {
 
    @Autowired
    private BatchService service;
```

And added my TaskLet in my configuration:

```java
@Autowired
private CrawlerTask crawlerTask;
```