# Spring Batch -- Data not getting promoted to future Step

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

a data i'm putting in the `JobExecution` map is not getting promoted to a future Step.

This is the `XML` file:

```xml
<batch:job id="job1">
    <step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet1">
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:next on="SUCCESS" to="tasklet2"/>
        <batch:end on="STOP"/>
        <batch:listeners>
            <listener ref="promotionListener1"/>
        </batch:listeners>
    </step>

    <step id="step2">
        <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet2">
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:listeners>
            <listener ref="promotionListener2"/>
        </batch:listeners>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="tasklet1" class="....Tasklet1" scope="step">
</bean>
<bean id="tasklet2" class="....Tasklet2" scope="step"/>

<bean id="promotionListener1" class="org.spr....ExecutionContextPromotionListener">
    <property name="keys" value="key1"/>
</bean>
<bean id="promotionListener2" class="org.spr....ExecutionContextPromotionListener">
    <property name="keys" value="key2"/>
</bean>
```

This is the Java files for `Tasklet1` & `Tasklet2`.

```java
public class Tasklet1 implements Tasklet, InitializingBean, StepExecutionListener {

  private StepExecution stepExecution;

  @Override
  public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
  }

  @Override
  public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
    ...
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list = dataMapper.retrieveData();
    ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
    stepContext.put("key1", list);
    logger.info("list put: " + stepContext.get("key1"); // list put: [132, 943, 4]
    ...
  }
}
```

```java
public class Tasklet2 implements Tasklet, InitializingBean, StepExecutionListener {

  List<Integer> list;

  private StepExecution stepExecution;

  @Override
  public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
    ExecutionContext jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
    this.list = (ArrayList<Integer>) jobContext.get("key1");
    logger.info("list retrieved: " + stepContext.get("key1"); // list retrieved: null
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
  }

  @Override
  public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
    ...
    Integer packetNumber = dataMapper.retrievePacketNum();
    ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
    stepContext.put("key2", packetNumber);
    ...
  }
}
```

i am using 2 different listeners, to promote 2 different data, each mapped to `key1` & `key2`.

it's not working because in the log statement in `Tasklet2`, i can see the object retrieved from the `key1` key is null

**Additional Note**:

- `tasklet1` has the `batch:next` configuration, not sure if that's causing the `ExecutionContext` to not get promoted

anyone able to help me troubleshoot?

---

I was able to retrieve the data in the next `Step` by using the following code instead, reference was [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52271942/15781733).

```java
@BeforeStep
    public void retrieveInterStepData(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        Collection<StepExecution> stepExecutions = jobExecution.getStepExecutions();
        for (StepExecution steps : stepExecutions) {
            ExecutionContext executionContext = steps.getExecutionContext();
            if (executionContext.containsKey("keys")) {
                this.nationalityMap = (Map<String, String>) executionContext.get("keys");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The XML code that defines `promotionListener1` in this question seems to use the same notation that does not work as reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77057716. You should use the `util` namespace and provide the keys as an array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77057969/5019386. Other than that, I see nothing obviously wrong with what you shared, and the promotion should work.