# Spring batch - how to read fields and actual data from specific section of file?

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to spring batch and need some help in parsing this file.
I need to read this sample file where contents are between START_OF_FILE and END_OF_FILE tags.
I need to read list of fields from START_OF_FIELDS and END_OF_FIELDS and then based on that read columns from START_OF_DATA and END_OF_DATA section.
How can I read specific section of the file and read subsequent lines based on what was read from pervious section ? Thank you for your help in advance.

```
START_OF_FILE
STARRT_OF_FIELDS
COL2
COL3
END_OF_FIELDS
START_OF_DATA
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4
END_OF_DATA
END_OF_FILE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a custom `ItemReader` implementation for such use case. Your implementation could use the [SingleItemPeekableItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/SingleItemPeekableItemReader.html) to peek items ahead and detect the next line to be read. You can find a few examples [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/SingleItemPeekableItemReaderTests.java).

Comment: Thank you @Mahmoud. I am new to and still learning spring batch. How can I get Field names separately and then data lines separately ?

Comment: I would proceed in two steps: step1 (simple tasklet) does the necessary checks and calculations (detect fields, the line where acutal records start, etc) and a second step (chunk-oriented) which reads items line by line. Step 1 can pass infos to step 2 via the job execution context, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292667.

Comment: Thank you again @Mahmoud. I will try this.

Comment: Thanks again @Mahmoud. It is working as expected by using SingleItemPeekableItemReader