# Is it possible to pass large objects from one step to another in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, chunks, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-job-monitoring, jobexecutiondecider

The requirement is to pass large objects from one step to another in a conditional flow  where we should be able to modify the objects data as well. According to the docs we can promote it to the job execution listener but from what I've read the drawback of this way Is that large objects can't be stored in this method, what would the suitable production grade solution be for this requirement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we share data between the different steps of a Job in Spring Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292667/how-can-we-share-data-between-the-different-steps-of-a-job-in-spring-batch)

Comment: It is possible, but not recommended. See details in the answers of the duplicate question.